# Cosa significa "berci sopra"?

Tags: idioms, meaning

Un altro dei modi di dire che appare in [questo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=EvNqzBHCdwc) è "berci sopra". Ho trovato [questa spiegazione](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/sopra.php) nel dizionario Hoepli:

> fig. per riuscire a dimenticare qualcosa o qualcuno.

Dunque, "berci sopra" significa bere per cercare di dimenticare qualcosa o qualcuno?

Comment: Sí, ci sono altri modi di dire simili, come "dormirci sopra" o "pensarci sopra" (con significati differenti, naturalmente).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significa non pensare più a un problema e bere degli alcoolici per distrarsi.

Comment: ...o magari più per stordirsi.  :-)

Comment: … o per dimenticare. :-D

Comment: Io personalmente non lo associo all'ubriachezza, ma solo al fare qualcosa di piacevole (bere) per non pensare a qualcosa di triste.